# ajax cart success hide div and display another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using ajaxify for some add to cart funcionality of my shopify collection page.
All works fine however I need to hide a div once the item has been added to cart and display another. 
The Html looks something like this

```
<div class=“col-add-to-cart”>
    <div class="col-add-btn-container">
        <button type="submit" name="add" class="add-to-cart-main" data-add-to-cart="">
            <span data-add-to-cart-text="">Add to cart</span>
        </button>
        <p class="ajaxified-cart-feedback success" style=""><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Added to cart! <a href="/cart">View
            cart</a> or <a href="/collections/all">continue shopping</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-container">

        <div class="col-add">
            <div class="expand-icon expanded">
            </div>
            <div class="checkmark">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the relevant JS

```
$addToCartBtn.addClass('inverted');
_setText($addToCartBtn, _config.addedToCartBtnLabel);
_showFeedback('success', '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Added to cart! <a href="/cart">View cart</a> or <a href="/collections/all">continue shopping</a>.', $addToCartForm);
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $addToCartBtn.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled').removeClass('inverted');
    $('.col-add-to-cart').find('.expand-icon.expanded').css("display", "none");
    $('.col-add-to-cart').find('.checkmark').css("display", "block");
    _setText($addToCartBtn, _config.addToCartBtnLabel);
}, _config.howLongTillBtnReturnsToNormal);
```

So as you can see I'm setting the checkmark to `display: block` and hide the `expand-icon.expanded`.
This works for the expand-icon as only one on the page has the `.expanded` class, however it shows all the `.checkmark` divs for each product. I only need it to display for the checkmark within the same container div as the `.ajaxified-cart-feedback .success`  div. I've tried to do that with the `col-add-to-cart container` but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to limit your query to a certain scope. From the info you provided I can't tell for sure what is happening, but you could try replacing `$('.col-add-to-cart')` with `$addToCartBtn.closest('.col-add-to-cart')`

The first one will select every element on the page with that class, causing the effect you observed. The second will start from `$addToCartBtn` (which I am assuming is a single element, in the context you need), find its closest parent with 'col-add-to-cart', then allowing you to "find" within the right context.

You could also try starting the query from `$addToCartForm`. It is not clear which element it refers to, but if it works for `_showFeedback`, it might work for your case too. That would look like this: `$addToCartForm.find('.checkmark').css("display", "block");`